# Multiple playlists with PlaylistBroadcaster

Tags: linux, streaming

In Darwin Streaming Server 5.5.5 run on Linux.

I am having issues starting multiple playlists with PlaylistBroadcaster.  I seem to be hitting a limit at 22 simultaneous playlists.  Once I try to launch the 23th, I get the following error.

```
2009-07-09 09:39:38: FATAL: Out of File Descriptors. 
Set max connections lower and check for competing usage from other processes. 
Exiting.
```

And all PlaylistBroadcaster processes gets killed.

```
# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
386132

# ulimit -n
1024
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get from `ulimit -n`?  That should give you your "Maximum number of open file descriptors" per process.

Edit:
You can see how many file descriptors a process is using by following the instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html) and [here](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html).

Resource limits can be set for users at login time by editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  See `man limits.conf` and `man pam_limits` for details.

Comment: [root@darwin ~]# ulimit -n

Returns:
1024

Comment: Anything else I should add to the problem description?

Comment: Try 'ulimit -n 2048' before starting the server from the same shell (it affects the current shell, and is inherited by any processes it starts).  You may need to add it to the server's start script.

Comment: Also, this shown how to see how many file descriptors are used by a process: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html

Comment: There's also: http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html

Comment: Great it helped!

Can I make the ulimit change permanent on the server?

Comment: On Debian it's set in '/etc/security/limits.conf'.  See 'man limits.conf' and 'man pam_limits' for more info.

Comment: Very excellent. Cheers.